# Why can't I do an adaptive order on Futures Options?

Tags: options, futures, interactive-brokers

Interactive Brokers has the ability to adaptive algorithmic orders that (I'm simplifying this greatly) can split the difference in the bid ask price without human intervention. I can do these types of orders for equity and index options but not futures options. Does anybody know why? I don't like to submit plain old market orders since I want to get the best price possible.

Answer (score 1):

Interactive Brokers offers adaptive algorithmic orders for equity and index options.  They do not offer them for futures or for futures options (see their web page that lists available order types for each of these securities).

As to why they don't offer this order type on futures, you'd have to call them for that explanation.